# Heroku slug size exceeded

Tags: heroku, deployment

[Error Slug size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3uVdV.png)

Hello ,
I tried to deploy my application , it s a face detection app using .
i want it to be online , when the user opens the link the camera gets open and it detects if he is wearing a mask or not in a bokeh output . but when i deploy it says compiled slug size is too big (over 500 mb) but in reality the projet size is below 30mb.

Comment: "See: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/slug-size"—well, did you take a look at that article?

Comment: [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: thank you for the answer Chris and sorry for that i m not used to stackoverflow yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your `requirements.txt` to only include the modules your really need and use, this should reduce the app footprint.

If this is not possible the alternative is to use the [Heroku Docker Registry](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime): build and push a Docker image of your application, the slug size limitation is not enforced with this type of deployment.