# How to increase Heroku Slug Size for small app?

Tags: python, heroku

I built as small, rudimentary ML app and I'm trying to deploy it in Heroku. All my requirements.txt files are correct, but I keep getting slug size exceeds 500. I went back to my model, deleted any libraries that were unneeded and cleared the heroku cache, but I'm still getting the slug size error. Is there a way to allow for a slightly larger Slug Size, or an easy way to decrease my slug? I only have the template, pickle file, and the requirements.txt file in the folder. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

[image][image]

Comment: Hope this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65759687/9095551

Comment: There is no way to increase the maximum slug size on Heroku. Figure out how to _decrease_ your slug size or use another host. (Or deploy using Docker, which [is not subject to size limits](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#known-issues-and-limitations)).